# Symbol for Mutual Inclusive events

Tags: probability, notation

is there any symbol for mutual inclusive(opposite of Mutually exclusive) events in probability.

I meant to say is for OR we have `U` symbol in Set Theory. Likewise is there any symbol for Mutual Inclusiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to say that two events $A$ and $B$ satisfy

1. If $A$, then $B$;
2. If $B$, then $A$.

That is, $A$ if and only if $B$.  Thus $A$ and $B$ are mutually inclusive if and only if $A$ and $B$ happen simultaneously.  We might say that $A$ and $B$ are *equivaent events*, or that $A$ and $B$ are *concurrent events.* (I don't think either notation is standard.)

Symbolically, I suppose you'd want to use $A \equiv B$ or $A=B$ (denoting the fact that mutual inclusion is an equivalence relation).  I don't think any particular form is standard.

Comment: How about $A=B$?